# Android Studio Resource Linking Failed for Resource xml Not Found

Tags: android

I getting This Error

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Z9F4\AndroidStudioProjects\TodoList\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:29: error: resource xml/text_view_circle (aka com.example.todolist:xml/text_view_circle) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuJZZ.jpg) come out when i run my simulator

[This is my text_view_circle.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CMaF.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/cyan"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#fff"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:topRightRadius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

[This is my AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Hya.jpg)

[SecondPage of AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Wif.jpg)

[ThirdPage of AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzNwJ.jpg)

Help me to solve it :< thanks! I confuse it for long time :<

Comment: Hello @Z9F4. Welcome to Stack Overflow. It may be helpful to read (How do I ask a good question?)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask].

Also, instead of uploading screen shots of your AndroidManifest, it may be more proper to copy and paste it as code using the markdown format "```code here```"

As for your issue, does your xml resource reside in `scanner\app\src\main\res`? Without knowing your app structure, that would be my first guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest you have written

<meta-data ..
android:resource="@xml/text_view_circle"/>

which  should be

<meta-data ..
android:resource="@drawable/text_view_circle"/>

as you have your text_view_circle.xml in drawable folder